Split data in oracle
I have one table emp:
  CREATE TABLE EMP 
   (ID NUMBER, 
    DES CLOB);

Actual data in table:
id   desc
1    I have pen in India
2    My name is pravin

Create function using loop when data length size more than 6 then other data is next row in oracle.
output
id   desc
1    I have
1     pen i
1    n India
2    My nam
2    e is p
2    ravin

converting clob to varchar

You forgot to ask a question. Do you have one or should we close this "question"?

Inspire of the query to wrap the code in the kind of function you need:
with data(id, txt) as (
    select 1, empty_clob() || 'I have pen in India' union all
    select 2, empty_clob() || 'My name is pravin'
)
select id, dbms_lob.substr(txt, 6, 6*(level - 1)+1) as descr
from data
connect by prior id = id and dbms_lob.substr(txt, 6, 6*(level - 1)+1) is not null and prior sys_guid() is not null
;


You can use a recursive query:
WITH bounds (id, des, position) AS (
  SELECT id, des, 1 FROM emp
UNION ALL
  SELECT id, des, position + 6
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  position + 6 <= LENGTH(des)
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET order_id
SELECT id,
       SUBSTR(des, position, 6) AS str
FROM   bounds

Or, from Oracle 12, use a LATERAL join to a row-generator:
SELECT id,
       SUBSTR(des, position, 6) AS str
FROM   emp e
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT 6 * LEVEL - 5 AS position
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL * 6 - 5 <= LENGTH(des)
       )

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE EMP (ID, DES) AS
SELECT 1, EMPTY_CLOB() || 'I have pen in India' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, EMPTY_CLOB() || 'My name is pravin' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, EMPTY_CLOB() || LPAD('A', 4000, 'A') || 'B' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ID
STR




1
I have


1
 pen i


1
n Indi


1
a


2
My nam


2
e is p


2
ravin


3
AAAAAA


...
...


3
AAAAB



fiddle
